# Comparing a string of numbers with an int

Tags: java, arrays, list

I'm taking in a String of a movie's release year, and an `ArrayList` of films (String title, int release year, `enum` genre etc...). The parameter String year is the users input of search which will be compared to each film to find a film that has the matching release year.
The matches will be saved into an `ArrayList`. By keeping the parameters as (String year, `ArrayList` films), how can I compare the first digit of the user's search input to check if it is an int to carry on finding a film match, otherwise return an empty `ArrayList` rather than returning a null one?

```
public ArrayList<Film> compareYear(String year, ArrayList<Film> films)                          
{
    for(int i=0;i<10;++i) {
        if(year.valueOf(year.charAt(0)).equals(i))    //check if it's an int
        {
            int releaseYear = Integer.parseInt(year);
            ArrayList<Film> releaseYearMatches = new ArrayList<Film>();
            for(Film f : films)                   //search through ArrayList of films
            {
                int releaseYears = f.getYear();         //gets the year for each film and compares it to user input search "year"
                if(releaseYears == releaseYear) {
                    yearMatches.add(f);
                }
            }
            return yearMatches;
        }
    }
    ArrayList<Film> nothing = new ArrayList<Film>();        
    return nothing;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For this, you can just use parse exception to detect if the year string is a number or not.

```
public ArrayList<Film> compareYear(String year, ArrayList<Film> films)                          
{

        try
        {
            int releaseYear = Integer.parseInt(year);  //if the string is not an integer, then it will automatically jump to the catch block
            ArrayList<Film> releaseYearMatches = new ArrayList<Film>();
            for(Film f : films)                   //search through ArrayList of films
            {
                int releaseYears = f.getYear();         //gets the year for each film and compares it to user input search "year"
                if(releaseYears == releaseYear) {
                    yearMatches.add(f);
                }
            }

            return yearMatches;
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
          ArrayList<Film> nothing = new ArrayList<Film>();

          return nothing;
        }
}
```

Sample code similar to this is run here - http://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/mu2b0X

Answer (score 1):

You should start with checking if the input string in numeric. If it is, you can proceed with the comparison.

You also have a mistake in the comparison as you're comparing `String` to`int` with the `==` operator which will compare the `String` reference to the `int` value. You need to either compare 2 `int` values with == (which works as an equality oerator for primitives) or `Object.equals(..)` for 2 `String` values.

There are plenty ways to check if `String` is numeric.
You can implement it yourself as follows:

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String str) {  
  try {  
    double num = Double.parseDouble(str);  
  }  
  catch(NumberFormatException e) {  
    return false;  
  }  
  return true;  
}
```

Or if you can use 3rd party jars you can use [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) and its method [StringUtils.isNumeric(CharSequence cs)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNumeric-java.lang.CharSequence-)

And last, your comparisong should look as follows:

```
if(isNumeric(year)) {
    int numericYear = Integer.parseInt(year);
    for(Film f : films) {
        int releaseYear = f.getYear();
        if(numericYear == numericYear) {
            yearMatches.add(f);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## `Year` class

Rather than use a mere `int` to represent a year value, use objects of the class intended for that purpose: [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Year.html).

To convert from your input string to such an object, call [`Year.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Year.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-). If the input is faulty, such as containing non-digit characters, an exception is thrown. Trap for that [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html) to decide to return your empty `List`.

```
Year y = null ;
try{
    y = Year.parse( input ) ;
} catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
    List< Film > list = Collections.emptyList() ; // Immutable empty list of type `Film`.
    return list ; 
}
```

Change the type of your year member on your `Film` glass from `int` to `Year`. Compare by calling `equals`, `isBefore`, `isAfter`.

```
if( y.equals( film.getYear() ) ) { … }
```